# :hi Vertsplit doesn't run on autocmd from init.vim

Tags: vim, neovim, autocmd

I've been setting up my init.vim file to use NeoVim on Windows 10, and ran into an issue I'm struggling to understand.

At the start of my file, I set up a couple of :hi(ghlight) autocmds, and only the VertSplit seems to be ignored on starting. Even worse, I can run the command in the vim cmd bar and it'll work just fine.

Here's a snippet:

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=longest:full,full  " get bash-like tab completions
"set cc=120                   " set an 80 column border for good coding style
filetype plugin indent on   " allows auto-indenting depending on file type
set tabstop=4               " number of columns occupied by a tab character
set shiftwidth=4            " width for autoindents
set softtabstop=4           " see multiple spaces as tabstops so <BS> does the right thing
set number
set mouse=a
set undofile
set cursorline
set splitright

autocmd VimEnter :set laststatus 3<CR>
" THIS WORKS
autocmd VimEnter :hi CursorLine cterm=None guifg=#5c6773<CR>
" THIS DOESNT
autocmd VimEnter :hi VertSplit cterm=None guifg=#5c6773<CR>
```

Any help/advice on this? I've been googling but can't find anything about VertSplit or similar. Can also post the full conf if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not a matter of googling. It's a matter of studying the documentation for the thing you are about to use and *then*, applying what you learned.

First, an autocommand is supposed to be made of *at least* these elements:

```
autocmd <event> <pattern> <command to execute when the pattern matches>
```

but you didn't specify a pattern for any of your three autocommands. This is easily fixable:

```
autocmd VimEnter * :set laststatus 3<CR>
autocmd VimEnter * :hi CursorLine cterm=None guifg=#5c6773<CR>
autocmd VimEnter * :hi VertSplit cterm=None guifg=#5c6773<CR>
```

Second, the `<command>` part is always an Ex command so you can drop the useless colon:

```
autocmd VimEnter * set laststatus 3<CR>
autocmd VimEnter * hi CursorLine cterm=None guifg=#5c6773<CR>
autocmd VimEnter * hi VertSplit cterm=None guifg=#5c6773<CR>
```

and the useless—and very likely to cause errors down the line—`<CR>`, which is really only useful in normal mode mappings:

```
autocmd VimEnter * set laststatus 3
autocmd VimEnter * hi CursorLine cterm=None guifg=#5c6773
autocmd VimEnter * hi VertSplit cterm=None guifg=#5c6773
```

Now that your autocommands actually look like autocommands, you should address the last remaining issue: `set laststatus 3`, which:

1. prints the current value of `laststatus`,
2. throws an "Unknown option" error for `3`.

Number options are set like this:

```
set optionname=999
```

so `set laststatus 3` should be:

```
set laststatus=3
```

Which leaves you with this mostly correct (and working, at least in my Vim) snippet:

```
autocmd VimEnter * set laststatus=3
autocmd VimEnter * hi CursorLine cterm=None guifg=#5c6773
autocmd VimEnter * hi VertSplit cterm=None guifg=#5c6773
```